# ¿ Cómo poner un objeto a "false" sin influir en el resto de GameObjects?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Tengo un generador de objetos en la pantalla y ese generador tiene 1 solo item.

Lo que pasa que cuando genera más de 1 objeto en la pantalla, pongamos 4, cuando toco uno de ellos me desaparecen todos , y sólo quiero que me desaparezca ese cuando pincho exactamente en él, no en la pantalla como hace mi código, qué me falta?

```
    public class Contador_dePuntos : MonoBehaviour {

    public GUIText tiempocontrol; 
    public int contador=0;
    public GameObject sphere;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {


    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (Input.GetMouseButton (0)) {
            sphere.SetActive(false); //AQUI PONGO FALSE PERO COMO SOLO HAY UN 
                                     // OBJETO SE ME PONEN TODOS FALSE

            contador++;

        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

**Generador**

```
    public class Generador : MonoBehaviour {


    public GameObject[] obj;

    public float tiempoMin = 2f;
    //public float tiempoMax = 3f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Generar ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
    }


    void Generar() {

        Instantiate (obj [Random.Range (0,obj.Length)], transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        InvokeRepeating ("Generar",1, 180);
    }
}
```

Comment: le pondre una respuesta pero tengo unas dudas, ese codigo es el generador de objetos entero?, si es asi como tiene 4 objetos en algun momento?

Comment: NO NO! ese solo es el de poner falso el objeto, el de generador te lo pongo ahora.

Comment: Y me salen 4 objetos porque tengo 4 generadores.

Comment: le deje una idea de como usarlo y alguno link porque igual se ajusta mas uno u otro, si tiene algun problema para implementarlo puede comentarmelo. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedo interpretar es que cada objeto tiene el codigo que usted pone.Y por ello cuando se aplica el if del update pone en false a todos los objetos que tenga creado en ese momento:

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    if (Input.GetMouseButton (0)) {
        sphere.SetActive(false); //AQUI PONGO FALSE PERO COMO SOLO HAY UN 
                                 // OBJETO SE ME PONEN TODOS FALSE

        contador++;

    }
}
```

Por ejemplo al tener 4 objetos con el mismo codigo el `if` si se cumple es para todos con lo que se ponen todos en false, al tener el mismo codigo.

Trate lo siguiente de alguna manera, `OnMouseEnter` por ejemplo:

```
void OnMouseEnter() {
        //
}
```

---

```
void OnMouseEnter() {
    if (Input.GetMouseButton (0)) {
        sphere.SetActive(false); //AQUI PONGO FALSE PERO COMO SOLO HAY UN 
                                 // OBJETO SE ME PONEN TODOS FALSE

        contador++;

    }
}
```

es solo una idea, puede que alguno de los siguiente se ajuste mejor a lo que quiere lograr.

---

puede mirar alguno de `OnMouse...`

- [OnMouseEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseEnter.html)
- [OnMouseExit](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseExit.html)
- [OnMouseOver](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseOver.html)

Tiene que tener presente esto:

> This function is called on Colliders marked as Trigger if and only if
>   Physics.queriesHitTriggers is true.

**Update:**

Quizas [OnMouseOver](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseOver.html) se ajuste mejor a lo que usted busca porque se llama mientras este sobre el objeto (collider/triger ect).

Comment: te pongo +1 porque he cambiado de idea y porque no me funcionó, abro otra pregunta, gracias.